# open certain files with OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I have a button in my program that when clicked opens OpenFileDialog and show all *.jpeg files that are in a certain path. Now, I want to show only those photo files that have "water" in their names not all files.
please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your filter from

```
filter = "Images |*.jpeg"
```

to

```
filter = "Images of Water |*water*.jpeg"
```